# "None of [] are in the columns" after pd.concat operation

Tags: pandas

**My Code**

```
test=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

**Resulting Data**

```
Convert_Hz  Real_SignChange
234 53.6533 -0.00233063
233 54.5993 -0.00212641
232 55.5868 -0.00201793
231 56.6018 -0.00182786
230 57.5971 -0.00183925
... ... ...
130 157.944 -0.000642894
129 159.01  -0.000330292
128 160.064 -0.000199488
127 160.985 6.86476e-05
126 161.635 -4.50584e-05
```

**What I have tried to combine the 2 columns and insert comma**

```
attempt 1:df['ID'] = df[['test']].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x), axis=1)
```

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['test'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

```
attempt 2:df['period'] = df[['Convert_Hz', 'Real_SignChange']].agg(','.join, axis=1)
```

`KeyError: "None of [Index(['Convert_Hz', 'Real_SignChange'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

**I have checked the name of the columns**

`test1.index`

**Result**

`Index(['Convert_Hz', 'Real_SignChange'], dtype='object')`

Not sure of the steps to resolve this...

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: It prints out a list of strings that exist in the excel file. I issued the following command to "overwrite" the name of 2 specific columns via `df1=dfnew['Convert_Hz'] and df2=dfnew['Real_SignChange']` So it seems Pandas is not reading the new names?

Comment: It seems you need `test=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)` and then `test['period'] = test.agg(','.join, axis=1)`

Comment: The 2 column names are strings but the associated series that I want to combine with the comma are floating numbers. For example I want to combine `53.6533 -0.00233063` as `53.6533, -0.00233063`

Comment: Your suggested command returns `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Comment: Sorry, then use `test['period'] = test.astype(str).agg(','.join, axis=1)`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. Thanks for your fast response and the new method type. How do I promote this answer to this question?

Comment: I think not necessary ;)